# geopandas merge GeoDataframe along another geometry

Tags: python, geopandas

I have a measurements GeoDataframe X. Each measurement has a location, that is not necessarily unique.
I have a result GeoDataframe Y. Each Point of its geometry is unique and spaced as wanted.
X is of the following form:

```
                 geometry  measurement
timestamp                                                            
126         POINT (x1 y1)     0.558624
1133        POINT (x2 y2)     0.188086
1953        POINT (x3 y3)     1.206570
3147        POINT (x4 y4)     2.327880
4154        POINT (x5 y5)     1.603011
```

And Y looks like that:

```
            geometry  value
id                                                       
0    POINT (x'1 y'1)    NaN
1    POINT (x'2 y'2)    NaN
2    POINT (x'3 y'3)    NaN
3    POINT (x'4 y'4)    NaN
4    POINT (x'5 y'5)    NaN
```

I want to aggregate the measurements of X in Y, like so:
For every point of Y, take the mean of all the values of X that are within a certain radius.

So far, here is what I have come up with:

```
Y['value'] = Y.geometry.apply(lambda point: X.loc[X.geometry.distance(point) < radius, 'measurement'].mean())
```

The geometries have altitudes, but let's forget them for this question.

This code works fine, but for large datasets it takes a very long time to execute, because of the hidden for loops involved.

How can I optimize this? **scipy.spatial.distance.cdist()** looks like it could help, but I am having trouble using it so far.

Answer (score 0):

For people looking for an answer, I managed to achieve this.

Here is the code:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import distance

@property
def x(self):
    return pd.Series(self.geometry.apply(lambda p: p.x), name='x')

@property
def y(self):
    return pd.Series(self.geometry.apply(lambda p: p.y), name='y')

@property
def z(self):
    return pd.Series(self.geometry.apply(lambda p: p.z), name='z')


gpd.GeoDataFrame.x = x
gpd.GeoDataFrame.y = y
gpd.GeoDataFrame.z = z

Y_geometry_tuple = (Y.x, Y.y, Y.z)
X_geometry_tuple = (X.x, X.y, X.z)
dist_matrix = distance.cdist(np.atleast_2d(Y_geometry_tuple).T, np.atleast_2d(X_geometry_tuple).T) < radius
meas_matrix = dist_matrix * np.atleast_2d(X['measurement'])
meas_matrix[meas_matrix == 0] = np.nan
Y['value'] = np.nanmean(meas_matrix, 1)
```

The computation speed greatly increased (300-400 times faster).